# Understanding callback functions

Tags: javascript, function, callback

```
const myFunc = (callbackFunc) => {
    let value = 50;
    callbackFunc(value)
};

myFunc(value => {
    console.log(value)
})
```

I do not understand how and why this block of code runs, my main issue is with the 'callbackFunc' parameter which has been sent right back into it's code block. I saw this on a pre-made video, it logs back the number '50' into the console. I really do not understand why?

I have tried re-writing the code as a function declaration as well to see if it will be clearer but i still cannot understand.

Comment: "*I have tried re-writing the code as a function declaration*" - can you show us that code, please? What in particular do you not understand? What do you mean by "*sent right back into it's code block*"?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through this code step by step.

```js
const myFunc = (callbackFunc) => { 
    let value = 50;
    callbackFunc(value);
};
```

This assigns an arrow function to `myFunc`. It takes one parameter: `callbackFunc` (which should be a function for `myFunc` to work). Inside the function, a variable named `value` is initialized with the value of `50`. Then, the `callbackFunc` is called, passing the value of the `value` variable (i.e. `50`) as the first argument.

```js
myFunc(value => { 
    console.log(value);
});
```

This calls `myFunc` and passes the arrow function `value => {console.log(value)}` as the first argument, which would be `callbackFunc` in `myFunc`. This function will be called with `50` as the first argument inside `myFunc`, so `value` (the first parameter) will be set to `50`. The function only calls `console.log` with that value, so `50` is output to the console.